# Android window resizing extremely slow

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I've implemented an activity which contains three tabs (using TabLayout). One of the tabs (implemented using a Fragment) has an EditText box at the bottom of the screen. When the focus shifts to the edit text box i.e when one selects the box, the soft keyboard appears immediately but the edit text box is shifted up after a significant lag. Similarly, when the back button is pressed the keyboard is hidden immediately but the edit text box moves down only after some time. Any ideas as to why this could be happening? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you testing it on an emulator?

Comment: It works perfectly on various emulators but the problem arises only on an actual device.

Comment: Try it on some other actual device and avoid Samsung device if you can.

Comment: Still working on the issue. Doesnt seemed to have solved the problem. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: can you share the xml code